# what Am I Find Out?

Tags: riddle

> I am a 5 letters word.
>
> If you remove the first letter I am a form of energy.
>
> Remove two and I'm needed to live.
>
> Scramble the last 3 and you can drink me down.

```
What am I?
```

Comment: 1. There are (at least) two possible solutions to this puzzle. And 2. I am pretty sure I have seen this puzzle before.

Comment: If you know two solutions then please tell at least one. can you provide the link if you find it is duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What am I?

> `wheat` or `cheat`

I am a 5 letters word.

> Both wheat and cheat contain 5 letters.

If you remove the first letter I am a form of energy.

> Heat

Remove two and I'm needed to live.

> You need to eat to survive.

Scramble the last 3 and you can drink me down.

> You can drink tea which is eat scrambled.